# SQL Server Performance: GROUP BY int vs GROUP BY VARCHAR

Tags: sql-server, performance, types, group-by

Is there a performance difference when grouping by different data types? For instance, if I group by INT, will I get better performance than if I group by varchar?

Comment: Depends on the size of the ints and varchars, if they're indexed or not, and the alignment of the moon - when it's ascendant in jupiter, b-tree indexes perform 0.03% worse than normal. You'll have to benchmark your specific case to figure out which is better.

Comment: @Marc B: All other things being equal. In general. Let's say int vs varchar(8)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say GROUP BY INT is faster, as only 4 bytes are checked verses n bytes in a varchar field.

Answer (score 3):

Are you deciding on a data type based solely on how the data type performs in a `GROUP BY`? Is it the same data, you're just deciding how to store 123456, as an `INT` or a `VARCHAR`? Have you given consideration to other factors, such as the CPU cost of converting between numeric and string types when it might not otherwise be necessary? The extra memory required to hold the whole table in cache? The row overhead for `VARCHAR` indicating length? What about storage costs (e.g. 1234567890 takes 4 bytes as an `INT`, but '1234567890' takes 10 bytes + row overhead as a `VARCHAR`)? How about compression? How will the index on this column be aligned with the clustered index on the table, which can affect how useful "already grouped" will be?

In other words, I wouldn't consider `GROUP BY` performance in a bubble.

Comment: Thanks, all great considerations. I'm considering GROUP BY in a bubble because in this case I really think all other things are equal. Yes it is the same data, and I am deciding on a data type based on the group by speed since that is the major function of this column (to provide groupings for sums). In addition, the column is part of the compound primary key, so it is part of the clustered index. Conversion to and from int or varchar will be done in equal amounts both ways, so again, equal.

Comment: Can I ask what is the actual data element this column represents?

Comment: @Richard - make sure the index is being used; there's no guarantee especially when it is made up of multiple fields and you are only using one of them. If you convert the field in your query to another type, the index won't get used at all.

Comment: @stack.user.999: FiscalPeriod example - 201108  (which is August 2011)

Comment: Have you considered using SMALLDATETIME? This is also four bytes for grouping but gives you all kinds of other advantages in working with date/time types.

Answer (score 2):

Grouping on an int would be slightly faster than grouping on a varchar, but what really makes a difference is if there is an index on the field that the database can use for the grouping.

Comment: Assuming there is an index on them both . . .

Comment: @Richard DesLonde: Then there should hardly be any difference, as the index is basically already grouped.